# Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I have a basic Rest program in which I'm using Liquibase. Was about to run it and this appears on the run: [image]

Not pretty sure on what to do to solve it

Comment: Try to reinstall it correctly based on the installation instructions.

Comment: What are you doing, is this a spring application that has a liquibase jar and it autoconfigures itself and runs an update? You did check to see if the change log is present in the classpath? There's a liquibase spring properties file, can you show that?

Comment: As a note, please enter your code snippets as code text instead of screenshot images. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a spring boot application, the default path for liquibase change log file can be overriden in application.yml file, following is one such example -

spring:
liquibase:
change-log: classpath:/liquibase/changelog-master.xml